# Advantage of using vector object as opposed to creating your own

Tags: c++, vector

Here is a data type I created to store a random amount of data.
I've tested the object and it stores the data and is able to receive it
(I've left out the functions that receive data since i don't think there relevant to the question)

```
 class MyDynamicArrayV2
 {

int* data;
int* tempArray;
int Position;
int Capacity;

void resize (int desiredSize)
{
    delete data;
    data = new int [desiredSize];
}

void copy (int* OrginalData,int* dataCopy, int OrginalData_length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < OrginalData_length; i++)
    {
        *(dataCopy+i) = *(OrginalData+i);
    }
}

   public :

MyDynamicArrayV2 ()
{
    data = new int [2];
    Position = 0;
    Capacity = 2;
}

void AddData (double Num)
{
    if ((Position+1)>Capacity)
    {
        tempArray = new int [(Capacity)+1]; // 
        copy(data,tempArray,Capacity); // Copy data to tempeoary storage
        resize(Capacity*2);// Resizes the array
        copy(tempArray,data,Capacity); // Restore data
        Capacity= Capacity*2;
        delete tempArray;
    }


        *(data+Position) = Num; // Allocates the data
        Position++;

  }

  ~MyDynamicArrayV2()
  {
    delete data;
  }

   };
```

I then tested the MyDynamicArray object against the Vector and list Container since these both are able to accept a random amount of data. I tested for speed using the following loop and for memory usage using task manager.

```
     t1 = clock();
 for (int i = 0 ; i <= 10000000; i++)
 {
    //MyDynamicArray.AddData(i);
    //MyVector.push_back(i);
    //Mylist.push_back(i);
 }
 t2 = clock();
 double diff = (double)t2-(double)t1;
 double seconds = diff/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 cout << seconds;
```

Results.
(MyArray: 0.473 seconds, 64.6 MB.)
(MyVector: 3.595 seconds, 46.2 MB)
(MyList: 16.987 seconds, 537.8 MB (What is the purpose of List??))

So my questions are how was the Vector class written? Why is my Object faster at allocating data compared to the Vector Object. Why is the vector object using less Memory than my Object?? And are you better of creating your own data type depending on the situation??

Side note: I also tested the speed at which my object and the vector object could access the data but they were both practically the same so i didn't add this test if anyone feels it is relevant please comment and i will add it.

Comment: Are you comparing the performance to the `std::vector<int>` and `std::list<int>` classes?  It's very hard for us to comment when we can see only the `MyDyanmicArrayV2` class, and not the type of `MyVector` and `Mylist`.

Comment: I'm confused. What "vector" are you talking about? `std::vector` or the `MyVector`?

Comment: You need to use the array form of delete (`delete[]`) to deallocate arrays dynamically allocated with `new[]`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am comparing The class I created MyDynamicArrayV2 with std::vector and std::list.

Comment: No you see it uses the copy function to store does values in a tempArray and then puts them back to data after it has been resized.

Comment: Is `resize()` a private method?

Comment: You are not profiling with a debug build by any chance?  The `std` containers run quite a bit slower with the iterator debugging enabled.

Comment: I have also added the delete [] and it has had no effect on the time or memory

Comment: Yes resize is a private method.

Comment: Changing to `delete[]` was intended to make your code correct, not more efficient.  Profiling incorrect code is a huge waste of time.

Comment: What is the difference between delete and delete [] though??

Comment: I may be compiling it with a debugger how would i check ??

Comment: `delete[]` is for releasing objects allocated with `new[]`.  Using `delete` on something allocated with `new[]`, or `delete[]` on something allocated with `new`, is undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry I was profiling in debug and vector is faster. But how does vector decide by how much to resize the array?? And is there any occasion where it would be advantageous to create your own Dynamic Array??

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Just to add to the confusion: sometimes you need to use `delete[]` even though there was no `[]` visible in the allocation! Here is an example: `typedef int array[10]; delete[] new array;` It is clear that an array object is allocated in this case but the `new`-expression alone is not sufficient! You need to take the type into consideration, too.

Comment: Try it out with an object where the constructor does some intialization. I'm betting `std::vector` will perform much more favorably than your implementation.

Comment: Likely because `std::vector` just carves out a chunk of memory but defers construction to later, for instance by using placement `new`. Your implementation however always default constructs the item type during initialization and resizing, regardless of whether all the items are used or not. That results in potentially a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: but i taught the if (position + 1 > capacity) in the AddData() function would make sure that the object only resized when it needed to ??

Comment: `new T [n];` will always default construct *n* instances of type `T`. Unless all *n* instances of those are used extra work is going to be done.

Comment: @greatwolf But wouldn't std::vector<T> also have to do the same thing, how does it know to create the exact number of memory spaces??

Comment: @ConorLinehan The idea is to separate memory allocation from object construction. The `sizeof(T)` is known so it's just a matter of deciding how fast you want capacity to grow. Multiple that by `sizeof(T)` and you have bytes needed to allocate. There are a few ways to do this, eg. custom allocator, possibly `malloc` or even using the memory allocation routines from the os API. You'll have to inspect `std::vector` header to see what the implementation really does.

Comment: Please move extended discussion to [chat], thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you code is certainly wrong: you allocate arrays but you release objects! At the very least you need to use `delete[] data;`. When testing your code against `std::vector<double>` on MacOS with gcc and clang, `std::vector<double>` consistently wins.

Did you compile with optimization? It is often quite deceptive to compile with debug mode: since `std::vector<T>` is heavily factored template code, not inlining the code is rather harmful. Your code barely calls any other function, i.e., it wouldn't suffer, e.g., from function call overheads. Since it keep copying twice upon resizing the array while `std::vector<T>` copy/moves just once in that case I'd expect `std::vector<T>` to be faster (which it is for me when compiling with optimization).

Comment: How would I compile with optimization ?? And does std:vector<T> only copy once?? Is there a way to see the std::vector<T> source code??

Comment: @ConorLinehan: I'm passing `-O3` to gcc and to clang. I don't know which compiler you are using but assuming you use an IDE, you'd probably need to build in "release" mode. Upon resizing, `std::vector<T>` allocates a bigger array, copies the objects over, puts it into place, and released the existing array: one copy per resize. Since `std::vector<T>` is a template, you can just look at the header. The code tends to be not entirely straight forward, though.

Comment: Sorry i just looked up how to change to release in visual studios 2012 and your right vector is faster. After looking at the header files I dont think I'll be able to figure it out its rather long. How does the Vector Class decide by how much to resize the array ??

Comment: @ConorLinehan: The standard doesn't mandate any particular resize strategy except that the growth has to be exponential (well, it doesn't really say that but it says that inserting `n` elements shall have complexity `O(n)` which implies the capacity grows exponentially). Doubling the current capacity seems to be a popular choice.

Comment: @Dietmer Thanks i figured out it had to grow exponentially when i first tried to recreate std::vector but i taught there might be a specific way to deceide by how much the array should be resized. Is there anything else about std::vector that i havint taught about in terms of performance??

Comment: @ConorLinehan: You are _teaching_ this stuff (or _thinking_ about it? I think _thought_ is the word you were looking for; sorry, I'm not a native English so this stuff got forced into me). Anyway, for non-built-in types your code suffers from default constructing all objects up to the capacity. Aside from potentially being expensive, it also means that the relevant type needs to have a default constructor which is not true for `std::vector<T>`. In addition, `std::vector<T>` can be used with a custom allocator which can improve memory management and its performance.

Comment: @Dietmer Sorry I am a native english speaker so i have no excuse. Oh I see so does std::vector<T> set aside a chunk of memory on construction?? And does the amount of memory it sets aside depend on how many elements are allocated on construction ?? Also is there any other way std::vector <T> trys to preempt how much memory is going to be allocated to it on construction to improve performance??